# Flutter SnackBar displays under CupertinoTabBar(hidding snackBar)

Tags: flutter, snackbar, cupertinotabbar

I have used BottomNavigatoinBar on root page. On one of the pages (Explore page) which is a stateful widget, It has a CupertionoSegmentedTab with three Tab and each displays listview.

I have to display SnackBar based on the listview item click. I can successfully show the SnackBar but It is hidden behind the BottomNavigatoinBar . Is there any solution I can display it above the BottomNavigatoinBar ?

Comment: I haven't used Cupertino stuffs but  did you try playing with elevations?

Comment: did you mean elevations with SnackBar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply adjusting the content of the SnackBar helped in my case as:

```
 Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content: SizedBox(
              height:70,
              child: Text(state.message.toString())),
        ),
      );
```

Although the above solution fixed my problem, according to the official docs its says SnackBar has behaviour option: floating, that cause [SnackBar] to be shown above other widgets in the
    [Scaffold]:

```
SnackBar(
content: Text("Slow Internet Connection..."),
behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,));
```